# Why remmina on Ubuntu refused to connect to Windows 7 (Service Pack 1)?

Tags: networking, server, windows-7, remote-desktop, remmina

I am confused and lost as to what to do next after having gone through the Internet for answer. I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on my laptop (WIFI) and Windows 7 (Service Pack 1) (Ethernet) on a desktop machine. I installed Remmina Remote Desktop Viewer on the laptop and enabled Remote Desktop Connection on Windows 7 machine. Based on the following question, [Why won't Remmina connect to Windows 7 Remote Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154121/why-wont-remmina-connect-to-windows-7-remote-desktop), I

1. Enabled port 3389 on my router and on my Windows 7 Firewall.
2. added the following changes in Remmina - RDP protocol, Windows IP address (192.168.1.33), Windows Username, Windows Password and RDP Security under advanced tab.
3. I even `rm ~/freerdp/known_hosts` even though there is nothing in that folder.
4. Checked to see if I can ping my Windows 7 machine from Ubuntu and Vice Versa. I can ping these machines back and forth with no trouble.
5. Even changed the security option under advanced to TLS as many have suggested online.
6. Even enabled network discovery and file sharing on the Window as a last resort.

Even after all that, Remmina on Ubuntu Laptop is REFUSING to connect to the Windows 7 machine. I simply don't know why. All Remmina says is "Connecting to "mywindow" for about 3 minutes. Then, it says Unable to connect to 192.168.1.33. That's it - no warning message box of sort.

**Additional information:**
On my Windows 7 window where you enable Remote Desktop Connection, there is only option to enable or disable remote desktop connection and it doesn't give you an option to select user.

[image]

I temporarily disabled the remote desktop connection as shown on the picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't have Remote Desktop on your Windows machine.  You only have Remote Assistance, [which is not the same thing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/what-is-the-difference-between-remote-desktop-connection-and-windows-remote-assistance).  Here's an image of what that box looks like on a computer that is equipped with Remote Desktop.

The [Windows RDC FAQ page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Remote-Desktop-Connection-frequently-asked-questions?b07aaca0) states

> You can't use Remote Desktop Connection to connect to computers
>   running Windows 7 Starter, Windows 7 Home Basic, or Windows 7 Home
>   Premium

[image]

Your best bet, IMHO, is to download tightVNC onto this windows machine and connect to it using Remmina and the VNC protocol.

Comment: Why would my Windows 7 not have Remote Desktop? Don't all the windows come with this feature? Is there a way I can install Remote Desktop on my Windows 7? If I install tightVNC, will not be opening myself to all sorts of hack or inbound attack?

Comment: @ThN It doesn't come in the lower priced version of Windows 7.  You would have to upgrade to Windows 7 Pro or something.  But this is really a Windows topic and not for this stack exchange site.  I updated the answer to include the Win 7 editions that are supported.  Since I've answered your actual question about why you can't connect, please consider accepting this answer by clicking the check mark.

Comment: You're very welcome.  Although Win 7 wasn't a bad OS, this kind of super annoying behaviour on the part of Microsoft is what sent me over to Linux.